# Jinja2 whitespace controls doesn't work as expected with IF block

Tags: jinja2

First of all: I read thoroughly documentation about whitespace control in Jinja documentation!

Have simple Jinja template:

```
New client has been created.

{% if not client.address %}!! Client does not have address{% endif %}
{% if not client.first_name or not client.last_name %}!! Client does not have first/last names{% endif %}

`C{{ client.id }} {{ client.full_name or "##MISSING##" }}

{{ client.status }}
```

When client hasn't address and first name it is rendering correct:

```
New client has been created.

!! Client does not have address
!! Client does not have first/last names

`C123 Some Name

pending
```

But when client has address or name:

```
New client has been created.




`C123 Some Name

pending
```

`if` expectedly produces empty lines.

Reason why I cannot user `{%- if -%}`: in this case second example rendering correctly BUT first example joins together both lines with "ifs".

Question: how to keep lines separate in the case then `if` conditions are true AND remove newlines when it falsy?

UPD: This is how I instantiate my Jinja environment:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader, select_autoescape

loader = PackageLoader("tally2bot", "templates")
env = Environment(
    loader=loader,
    autoescape=select_autoescape(["html", "xml", "jinja2"])
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this snippet below:

```
New client has been created.

{%- if not client.address %}
!! Client does not have address
{%- endif %}
{%- if not client.first_name or not client.last_name %}
!! Client does not have first/last names
{%- endif %}

`C{{ client.id }} {{ client.full_name or "##MISSING##" }}

{{ client.status }}
```

#### __ init__.py

```py
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader, select_autoescape

env = Environment(
    loader=PackageLoader("app", "templates"),
    autoescape=select_autoescape(["html", "xml", "jinja2"])
)
template = env.get_template('index.html')

print(template.render({'client': None}))
print('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
client = {
    'id': 123,
    'first_name': 'John',
    'last_name': 'DOE',
    'full_name': 'John DOE',
    'address': 'CA',
    'status': 'pending'
}

print(template.render({'client': client}))
```

#### result:

```py
(venv) PS D:\dev\python\app> py .\__init__.py
New client has been created.
!! Client does not have address
!! Client does not have first/last names

`C ##MISSING##

pending
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
New client has been created.

`C123 John DOE

pending
```